# Avoid pasting duplicate set of values in a column in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a basic thing but somehow not able to crack it.

I have to develop a simple macro using VB script in excel that can prevent users from pasting a set values in which duplicates are there.

For example, Under column A of an excel, if someone tries to copy following:

```
    cat  
    mat  
    rat  
    cat
```

Error must be thrown with a msg:

> "Trying to paste duplicate value"

I am able to right following code that reflect the duplicate message.

```
    Sub Highlight_Duplicates(Values As Range)
    Dim Cell

    For Each Cell In Values
      If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Values, Cell.Value) > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Duplicate Value"
    End If

  Next Cell
 End Sub

Private Sub Auto_Load()

 Highlight_Duplicates (Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10"))

End Sub
```

But I am unable to restrict the user from pasting the set of values.

Kindly advise.

Comment: You could possibly use the `Worksheet.Change` event, but you'd probably have to allow the paste, and then "undo" if there are dupes.

Comment: Yep, need to determine if duplicate before copy or after copy.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I need to restrain the user from pasting. Hence, need to determine duplicates before pasting. Also, value can be copied from anywhere, not just that worksheet or sheet. It can be copied from any csv too.

Comment: Maybe look into accessing the clipboard, but you can't tell if someone is going to paste can you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Worksheet_Change()` event `Application.Undo`

In the worksheet's code page that you want to track this activity/event you can do something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Test if it's the column we want. Test that only one thing was pasted.
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        'Test to see how many times this value is in use.
        'If greater than one, then undo the paste and yell at the user
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), Target.Value) > 1 Then
            Application.Undo
            MsgBox ("The value " & Target.Value & " is already present")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

One way to tackle multiple pasted values would be:
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        'Test if it's the column we want. Test that only one thing was pasted.
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then

```
        'Loop through each cell in the target range (as multiple may have been pasted)
        Dim TargetCell as Range
        For each TargetCell in Target.Cells

            'Test to see how many times this value is in use.
            'If greater than one, then undo the paste and yell at the user
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), TargetCell.Value) > 1 Then
                Application.Undo
                MsgBox ("The values pasted contained at least one duplicate. Duplicate found:" & TargetCell.Value)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next TargetCell
    End If
End Sub
```

These should serve as a good place to start and can be tweaked to do whatever you need to.

Comment: Hi @JNevil. First of all, thanks a lot for sparing your time. But the solution that you proposed is not actually working the way I was expecting. If I copy-paste one cell, it reflects 'error msg' correctly but if I copy the entire set of value again, it allows me to paste. So if cat,mat,rat are there in row 1,2,3 respectively and if I copy all 3 value again and try to paste, it allows pasting. But I try to paste just one value say 'cat', it correctly throws error.

Comment: That makes sense. You can see I anticipated only a single cell being updated at a time with that first `IF` statement (`Target.Cells.Count = 1`). That restriction should be removed, and then a new loop introduced like `For each TargetCell in Target.Cells` so that each value can pasted can be tested with that `Countif()`.

Comment: I just made an update that makes an attempt at multiple pasted values.

Comment: Oh yes. I see a typo and updated the answer. I'm glad you got it working! :)